# Horizontal alignment of an image in MS-Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

I am trying to align an image in Word document horizontally to "Centered" but when I put the Format setting--> Wrap Text: "In Line With Text"
OR "Top and Bottom", the image shifts to the right side of the page. How Can I have the setting Wrap Text: "In Line With Text" or "Top and Bottom" and the alignment of the image "Centered" horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do warp text and horizontal centered image at the same time. Best way is press enter before the image and keep the text above/below with "warp text" setting. now on the image right click and make centered.

Alternatively, use layout option as "with text wrapping" and select fix position on page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNDHC.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).